# Does changing from a .com website to .com.au hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress

Recently I made the change from a .com site that I have had for quite a few years and it has a lot of value. After completing my 301 redirects etc. to my .com.au site I have noticed a fairly significant drop in my (old) .com site organic traffic. I am just wondering if this is normal and if it will rise back up to the original levels?

Answer (score 1):

The `.au` will not give you a disadvantage in searching, but you will rank lower internationally and higher in Australia.

> Google is clear that “keywords in a TLD [i.e. domain ending] do not give any advantage or disadvantage in search.” This is bad news if you registered a domain name with one of these new domain endings hoping it would help you rank for a keyword, but it’s good news if you already have a domain name that doesn’t have a domain ending with a keyword, since it means you won’t face competition in your ranking from a “keyword” domain ending that didn’t exist when you bought your domain name.

> Specifically, if you purchase a domain name with a country-code TLD, Google will use that to geotarget your website. That means that if your business is in the UK and you get a .uk domain name for your website, your website will rank higher on search results pages in the UK.

From [Why your website’s URL is important for SEO](https://news.gandi.net/en/2021/12/why-your-websites-url-is-important-for-seo/)

Added from comment - redirecting from one domain to another will probably dilute your Google juice.

Comment: Absolutely.  Its probably also worth commenting that when you do 301 redirects you loose a bit of "Google Juice" because of the redirect.

Comment: I have always thought it sucks that Americans have no such limitations.  A dotcom is American and also international.  Why are the rest of us lumbered by this archaic geographic distinction, reminiscent of DVD encodings?

Comment: I think this is uncharitable. The Internet is really an American invention so this makes sense.  Conversely if I was American I'd be bitching about not having a way of geo-targetting using my domain name - after all, the whole world uses ".com" - and - if you think about it, it would only be fair that each state has its own TLD - after all a state is fairly analogous to a country in the EU.